# Python Passing a Function to an Object

Tags: python, oop, object, attributes

I am trying to create a class which allows users to create a custom button object, which holds the button's appearance attributes, as well as a function, which I want to be able to then run when I call the button's executeFunction() command.

```
def foo():
    print "bar"

class Button(object):

    def __init__(self, name, color, function):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.function = function

    # I want to be able to run the function by calling this method
    def executeFunction(self):
        self.function()

newButton = Button("Example", red, foo())
newButton.executeFunction()
```

Is this the correct way, or is there a specific way to perform this kind of action?

Comment: Is red defined?  You might be looking for "red" instead.

Comment: No, I just used it as an example, it would normally be an RGB tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, functions are objects too and can be passed around. There is a small error in your code and an easy way to simplify this.

The first problem is that you were calling the function `foo` while passing it in to your `Button` class. This will pass the result of `foo()` into the class, and not the function itself. We want to just pass `foo`.

The second nice thing we can do is just assign the function to an instance variable called function (or executeFunction if you want), and then it can be called via `newButton.function()`.

```
def foo():
    print "bar"

class Button(object):

    def __init__(self, name, color, function):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.function = function


newButton = Button("Example", red, foo)
newButton.function()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have

```
newButton = Button("Example", red, foo)
```

This passes foo, instead of passing the return value of foo, as your code did.

Comment: So if I pass in a function like that, I should be able to call it from a method perfectly fine?